# Rename the class in safe way?

Tags: .net

I have .NET project using VS 2010 Pro,
Some of the class name in App_Code is

- products (products.cs)
- commons (commons.cs)
- members (members.cs)

I think it is not good naming convention,so i would to rename that, however, if i use search (products) and replace to (clsproducts) , it possible replace some text which is not the class,so is it any tool to do that?

Comment: You can just rename only the class, then build and fix any compiler errors that occur.

Comment: I have to say it..."clsproducts" is even worse than "products" as a class name.  (1) Every keyboard since like 1970 has had a shift key.  Use it.  (2)  Hungarian-style type prefixes are deprecated in .net.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564(v=VS.71).aspx .

Comment: um...because in the project sql db, it has a table named [product], the Linq2SQL generator give it a name [products] for the data context, so i have to make a different name, is it any recommend for naming? Personally, i still using the Hungarian-style :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rename a class, just right click on it and select *Rename...*, that'll make sure that all references to it are renamed as well.

Comment: Yes~ it is good, so i can use the vs build-in function. thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the refactoring tools in VS. They work great  :)

Comment: NO!!! The builtin tools  :)  Right click on class name, select refactor, rename...

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace with preview option so unless your project is extremely large you can manually go through the list of changes and decide which ones to change.

Answer (score 0):

Changing filenames wouldn't be a problem. To rename a class name, just actually rename the class name in its deceleration statement, a red line would appear underneath it, hover your mouse pointer over it and click on `Rename` or `Rename with Preview`. It's gonna take care of everything, except if you have used some creepy smelly hard coded reflection techniques then it's gonna become a problem.